# Brevo API update contact (PUT request) - Error "duplicate_parameter"

Tags: python, odoo, put, sendinblue

In our Python code, we use the PUT-request of the Brevo API (https://developers.brevo.com/reference/updatecontact)  to update the attributes of each of our Brevo's contacts.

While in many cases, the response from the PUT update request is positive:

> response code:204

(see image in PJ),
in many other cases, this update on existing contact is refused (and not updated, with the error message (displayed in our log file):

> response["data"]["code"]: duplicate_parameter
> response["data"]["message"]: Unable to update contact, email is already associated to another

...it would be normal to have such an error message for a POST request to create a newcontact, but not for a PUT request to update an existing contact's attributes.

[image]

Could any one give me the reason of such apparently "random" behavior?